# Microsoft Excel Userform change cell colour if ListBox contains certain words?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am currently making an excel document to sort certain products, and show what components they contain. In my A Column, is the components, and in Row 1 is my products. I currently have 2 User Forms, 1 to add new components and another for new products. In my form for new products, I have the option to select any component that is in the 1st Column in a listbox, and then add it to a second listbox. I am now however unable to continue, I would like the corresponding cells between each product and its components to change colour depending on whether if uses each component. The document is:

[LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WRppq23i1sRZjGigbwAuIoCSovp_juf2/view?usp=sharing)

Note: This excel document is macro enabled, and will need to be downloaded and ran, cannot be used through the default google sheets it may open in.

Comment: CommandButton4 is currently my 'finish' button to submit the data.

Comment: Since your ListBox1 is a copy of Sheet1!A:A you can read the matching cell address from the list box, like `Sheet1.Cells(ListBox1.ListIndex + 1, 1)` and set that cell's color as you desire. This is a stylized solution. In practice it needs to be adapted to get the `ListIndex` of selected items and then add a procedure that removes the color from all unselected items.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I am a little bit lost as to what you're referring to. Could you possibly provide a small sample of code of how that would work? I have never done this before. I need to set the colour of each cell below the products. So not every component will be a difference colour depending on the product it is under.

Comment: I am also finding it difficult as the components and products are not always in the exact same order. I have made macro buttons to sort them alphabetically from A-Z or Z-A, which means all the cells in-between also move. This is good as it keeps the information relative to each product and component however I am unsure how to reference these cells if they constantly switch places.

Comment: If the list box is populated after the sort the solution I suggested above still works. Else, you need to conduct a search using the `Find` method. That's extra code which takes extra time to execute and you should rather try to solve the problem by sequencing your actions for best efficiency. Refocus your question in this thread not to look for a solution to your problem but to break through the point where you are stuck, not for someone to do your work but for someone to help you do yours.

Answer (score 0):

here is my version:

Start with fill a Listbox with words when workbook open. I need this for my test but I assume you already have some texts in your.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Feuil1.ListBox1
        .AddItem "Blue"
        .AddItem "Red"
        .AddItem "Green"
    End With
    
    With Feuil1.ListBox2
        .AddItem "Blue"
        .AddItem "Red"
        .AddItem "Green"
    End With
End Sub
```

And now just change the background color of the target cell based on the selected listbox word

Update from comments: Compare 2 Listboxes and color a cell if matching.

```vb
    Private Sub ListBox1_Click() 
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A1")
    
        Select Case ListBox1.Text
            Case "Blue"
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            Case "Red"
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case "Green"
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Case Else
        End Select
        
        ListBoxMatch
        
    End Sub
    

    Private Sub ListBox2_Click()
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("B1")
    
        Select Case ListBox2.Text
            Case "Blue"
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            Case "Red"
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case "Green"
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Case Else
        End Select
        
        ListBoxMatch
    End Sub
```

Adding a "ListBoxMatch" sub triggered after every click on each listbox1 or 2.

```vb
Private Sub ListBoxMatch()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("C1")
    
    If ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex) = ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListIndex) Then
        rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Else
        rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

C1 will be green or black if the listboxes are matching or not.

Mismatch:

[image]

Match:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I do have one more step that I'd require though. When choosing the range of the cell I want to change the colour of, I need it to correspond to the same row as that text displayed in column A. This does need to be 'adaptive' as the arrangement of the column A changes, so that they are still in the same row.

Comment: My current thoughts branching on your idea are something along the lines of; if (text in A1) is in (listbox 2), C1=Green, (and just have default colour as red), then always add the products into the same column (eg always into column C). Then its always drawing the text in the order its been arranged in.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add a color matching between 2 listboxes (if A1 = B1 then C1 = green)